# Array of ListBox Names from a Tab C#

Tags: c#, listbox, controls

I have a tab control that has listboxes on it some of which are created and named dynamically so I can't statically program their name.  Is there a way to create an array of all the list box names on a give tabPage?  I have been going nuts trying to figure out a way to do it.

Comment: you mean you want to fetch all the listbox names in a tab control? is this winforms, wpf?

Comment: @ricky  Yes.  I a trying to grab the dynamically created names, so I can't statically code them.

Comment: By far the simplest and most reliable approach is to not lose it in the first place.  You can store them in, say, a `Dictionary<TabPage, List<ListBox>>` and add them to the dictionary when you add them to a tab page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would look something like this (based on a winforms example)

```
List<string> listBoxNames = new List<string>();

    foreach (Control control in tabPage1.Controls)
    {
        if (control.GetType() == typeof(ListBox))
        {
            listBoxNames.Add(control.Name);
        }
    }
```

Or the same thing in linq syntax

```
    List<string> listBoxNames = (from Control control in tabPage1.Controls 
                                 where control.GetType() == typeof (ListBox) 
                                 select control.Name).ToList();
```

if you want to find all the listbox's in the tabpage again then see below

```
            foreach (var listBoxName in listBoxNames)
            {
                ListBox listBox = (ListBox) tabPage1.Controls.Find(listBoxName, true)[0];
            }
```

Comment: This seems promising, I am using C# winforms in VS2013.  I will check it out and let you know.

Comment: did the solution help?

Comment: The new issue is calling the listbox  name as a list box s oI can refer to the items held within.  meh..problems beget problems

Comment: thats simple, you just need to iterate through the listbox names and find, I've updated the answer above